# Access GitHub repo from CloudBuild

Tags: git, github, ssh, google-cloud-build

I am using Google CloudBuild as a CI server. It is using a mirror-repo of my GitHub repo to detect/pull changes, which works perfectly fine.

My problem is that once CloudBuild has successfully run all my tests, I want it to add a tag to my repo. I am using the `gcr.io/cloud-builders/git` container, but I can't push tags directly since this is only connected to the mirrored repo. So, to get around this, I am using a shell script to clone the repo directly from Github to actually create a tag.

When I try to access Github from Cloudbuild, I get the following error message:

```sh
Step #3: debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
Step #3: Host key verification failed.
Step #3: fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Step #3: 
Step #3: Please make sure you have the correct access rights
Step #3: and the repository exists.
```

Here is the script I am using (it just tests github access):

```sh
#!bin/sh

# Copy private key to ~/.ssh directory
cp ./path/to/my/key ~/.ssh/github
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/github

# Create SSH config file
cat >~/.ssh/config <<EOL
Host github.com
  HostName github.com
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github
EOL
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/config

# Add key to agent
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
ssh-keyscan github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
ssh-add -k ~/.ssh/github

# Set GIT config
git config --global user.name "myusername"
git config --global user.email "myusername@users.noreply.github.com"

# Test authentication with Github
ssh -T git@github.com
```

Another relevant part of the debug logs is this:

```sh
Step #3: debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
Step #3: debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 1: Applying options for github.com
```

It seems to be reading from `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` instead of the `~/.ssh/config` file I created.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

First, it is good practice to:

- name your Host entry `github` or `gh`, not `github.com`, in order to be sure to use the config file (since gh cannot be resolved by any DNS, while `github.com` can)
- include the `User git` as well in the config file: that way, the SSH URL to use becomes: '`gh`':

  ```
  ssh -Tvv gh
  ```

Second, if SSH reads only `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` instead of `~/.ssh/config`, that means the script is somehow launched as `root`, not as the user.